# Passing a custom parameter to a screen in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a table "Invoices" and a table "Checks". I've a screen to create the Invoices and a screen to create the Checks. In the Checks screen, I have a button "Select Invoices." Clicking the button will open the Invoices screen so that the user can select the invoices to add to the current Check.

In the Invoices screen I've added a command button "Add to Check" so when the user click the button the invoice is added to the Check.

Here's the a screenshot of the Invoices Screen.

[image]

Questions:

1. Is this approach a correct one? I mean, is there a better way to add the invoices to the check?
2. If this is the way to go then how I can pass the current Check instance to the Invoices screen so I can fill the Checks property in the Invoices table?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have two screens: an Invoices screen, and a Checks screen. What I would suggest are the following steps:

1. Create a checkId property on the Invoices screen
2. Mark the checkId property as a screen parameter
3. When you click the button and navigate to the Invoices screen, pass
   the id of the selected Check
4. On the created event of the Invoices screen, process the checkId
   property.
5. You can load the check object, then you can use that object to fill
   in the Checks property.

Comment: What you propose is the solution I used to solve the problem. But I wanna know if it's possible to pass the current Check entity to the Invoice screen because in the way you propose I've to Save() the Check before passing it as parameter because if the user is creating a new Check I don't have the Id so I've to save it to get the Id.

Comment: Yes this approach you would have to save the Check first to get the Id. another way is instead of redirecting to a new screen, you can use a modal window. Or use tabs as what Yann has suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this looks like a good approach
2. Based on your screen design, I don't see a need to open an invoice screen when you click the button.

All you need to do is:

**VB:**

```
Private Sub ButtonName_Execute
    If (Me.Invoices.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then Return

    Me.Invoices.SelectedItem.Check = Me.CheckProperty
End Sub
```

**C#:**

```
private void ButtonName_Execute()
{
    if (this.Invoices.SelectedItem == null) { return; }

    this.Invoices.SelectedItem.Check = this.CheckProperty;
}
```

This assumes that the name of the *Listado de Ofertas/Facturas* collection is *Invoices*, if its something else (like *Facturas*, for example, just substitute the actual name of the collection. The same deal with the CheckProperty name, just substitute the actual name of the Check property that the screen is bound to.

Comment: The screen you see in the screenshot is the "Invoices" screen and it has the list of invoices that match the filter condition, the filter is at the top of the screen and the button "Buscar" mean "Search", so once you click the "Search" button it lists all the Invoices that match the filter condition. So the user can click in the button "Agregar" (Add) and the Invoice is added to the selected Check in the Checks screen. Continue in the next comment ...

Comment: The screen with the Checks is the other tab "Crear Cheque". The Screen "Crear Cheque" has a button that when is clicked it opens this Invoices screen (what you see in the screenshot). What you propose is what I want but I don't know how to get the current entity in the Checks screen from the Invoices screen.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't realise that the invoices weren't on the same screen as the Check itself. What I would have done is have two tabs on the Check screen, one with a list of currently "unassigned" invoices (to choose from), the other with the invoices have been assigned to the Check, then it would have worked the way I showed in the code sample. You *can* do it with them on separate screens, but it can get a bit messy. Let me know if what I've just suggested suits you, or if you want to do it the "messier" way.

Comment: I agree with you that it's a bit messy having the Invoices in a separate screen but I need to add the filter on top of the screen to show only the filtered invoices because they can be thousands. Another way I thought was having a modal window in the Checks screen to show the Invoices screen but I don't know whether it's possible or not in LS

Comment: It's a matter of dealing with an entity in its whole. So if I create a Check entity, & I now need to add Invoices to that Check, I'd want a list of unallocated invoices to choose from (filtered however you need to reduce the numbers). Each time I select an Invoice & click Allocate, I just set the Invoice's parent property to the Check itself. Whether you do this in a single list, or if you have two lists (unallocated/allocated), each on a tab, or side-by-side on the screen, is up to you. But it's a simple, elgant solution to achieve what you need to do, no? I hope that made sense for you.